# Javascript - having trouble selecting an id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I gave my link a an id where if I click the link, I want my javascript to adjust the background image. I made a js-fiddle of a simple version of what I want here:

https://jsfiddle.net/qp8d390b/

```
<body background="http://www.blueskiescareers.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/blue-sky-clouds.jpg">
    <li>
        <a id = "attempt1" href="#top">SNOOPY1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>SNOOPY2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>SNOOPY2</a>
    </li>

    <div id= "#top">TOP PART </div>
</body>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[id='attempt1']").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('works');
        document.body.background = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/Fried_egg,_sunny_side_up.jpg";
    });
});
```

I'm new to selecting with javascript. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Here's a jQuery cheat sheet that might help you. http://oscarotero.com/jquery/. As Rory said jQuery uses CSS selectors. So, elements are selected by their name alone $('a') for links. Elements with an ID are selected with the # sign $('#attempt1') for any element with and ID of attempt1. $('a#attempt1') for an Anchor tag with the ID attempt1. $('.class') for an element with a class of 'class'. etc..

Comment: isn't this `$(document).ready(function()` should be this `jQuery(document).ready(function($)`?

Answer (score 1):

try to use `$("#attempt1")`

use # to get any id in html

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your HTML is invalid; `li` must be in either a `ul` or `ol` and all `a` elements must have either a `name` or `href` attribute.

Secondly, jQuery uses CSS rules, so to select by id is `$('#attempt1')`.

Lastly, to change the `background` CSS property to an image the URL string should be wrapped in `url()`. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#attempt1").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('body').css('background', 'url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/Fried_egg,_sunny_side_up.jpg")');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select it with :

```
$('#attempt1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `id-selector` in this case

https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

```
$("#attempt1")
```

The selector you used which is `attribute selector` is more used in inputs than in links (`a` elements)

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

You can find more info on jQuery selectors in

https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Hope it helps